# Issues Using .xib With Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, xib

Hey I'm trying to open a view controller that is designed using a xib interface file.  I am using the following lines of code to generate the controller from within a view controller created as a storyboard component.

```
YourViewController *viewController [[YourViewControlleralloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerName" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have never set up a view controller with a .xib before nor have I ever linked to one via storyboard so anything could be wrong.  Here is the error I am getting when I try to present the view.

> 2013-05-17 13:06:45.120 Coffee[8991:907] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the
>   "PeekPagedScrollViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was connected properly I had just forgotten to declare an initWithNibName method and therefore it crashed when I called it from storyboard.  Silly mistake but thanks for all the great feedback @matt

Answer (score 1):

Set the File's Owner in the .xib to the class of your view controller (perhaps it is called PeekPagedScrollViewController).

Then connect its `view` outlet to the main view in the .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Storyboard view controller custom class to your class name (the one your xib is also referencing), then in that same class, simply override `initWithCoder` with:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [[super initWithCoder:aDecoder] initWithNibName:@"YourCustomViewControllerXibsName" bundle:nil];
    if( self ) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

This will enable you to design layout and segue transitions in Storyboard, but design your layout in a standalone nib file.

Storyboard will handle instantiation, but when `initWithCoder:` is called, `initWithNibName:` will be the method that instantiates `self` via the xib.